# How to dynamically link json data to chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, graph, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart using json data. Currently I have the data within my script, but I would like to link it to a separate .json file within the project folder.

This is what I have currently:

```
    var jsonfile = {
        "jsonarray": [{
            "name": "Joe",
            "age": 12
        }, {
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 14
        }]
    };

    var labels = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
        return e.name;
    });

    var data = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
        return e.age;
    });

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Graph Line',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
            }]
        }
    });
```

Ideally, I would like the json data to be in a separate file so that it can be dynamically saved.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fs module to read and write to a file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonfile = fs.readFileSync('the/path');
//if you want to write to the file I gave you a link that shows you the way
```

For more information about the fs module you can check [File System | Node.js v12.6.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

You may need to pass by [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) and [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to save your object as a string in the file and to parse the string back to an object while reading the file.

Another manner that you may consider is lightweight javascript databases such as [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which is an embedded database in the browser side, or other databases such as [neDB](https://dbdb.io/db/nedb) if you want to persist data especially with an electron app.

Answer (score 0):

Have many way to use with your wish

```
var data = {"a" : "b", "c" : "d"};
```

then

```
<script src="data.js" ></script>
```

or

```
var json = require('./data.json');
```

or

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: when I tried: `var json = require('./data.json');` I got the error "require is not defined"

Comment: I have it downloaded, do I have to link it to my script?